# CSS style not applied on content replaced with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, replacewith

I have a div that I'm replacing dynamically with jQuery.

I do something like this:

```
$.get(url, function(result){
  $("#myDiv").replaceWith($(result));
}
```

The request is made correctly and the markup is loaded with no problem, but even if the content returned by the ajax call ("return") is exactly the same of #myDiv (it contains an element with the same id), some of the styles are not applied correctly.

The weirdest thing is that using Chrome, if I right click on the element with the wrong style and select "Inspect element", the style gets loaded just fine.

This works correctly on IE8.

Any idea on what can be causing this on Chrome?

Thanks

Comment: Are you implying that your stylesheet looks up the element by id? You might want to try specifying the styles via class and being sure to add the class onto your `result`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the redraw isn't triggering. You could try forcing a style change after the replacement like this:

```
$(some_selector_in_the_result).css('display','block');
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I just found a solution.

The element that wasn't being styled correctly was a div with an absolute position.

I was setting only the bottom position but not the left (which was 0).

I explicitly set the left in the CSS to 0 and now it looks fine.

Apparently the default position was different for some reason in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the jQuery function removeAttr('style') anywhere ? It is known for causing troubles sometimes with Chrome or other webkit browsers.
See http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9699

Comment: Nope, no style modification from js at all

Answer (score 0):

Chrome's DOM selectors are much more strict than IE8's.

I would suggest targeting the element by class rather than ID, even if it is unique to that element.

Comment: Tried this but it has the same behavior